# Is Downloading A Web Resource in CRM Online Dev Environment Slower Than a Prod Environment?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I have a Web Resource html page that I'm hosting in CRM.  It uses Kendo UI, which I also have hosted as a Web Resource in CRM.  This is the Chrome Network results when loading the page:

[image]

It's consistently taking 4+ seconds to download the 620KB js file.  This seems slow to me.  Would a production environment be faster?  Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although James has an excellent generic answer concerning script download time and environment differences, it doesn't answer the question at hand, will the prod environment be faster than the dev when it comes to downloading scripts?

I ended up moving my example to a production environment and unfortunetly there was no statistical difference between Dev and Prod.  Sometimes the Prod env was actually slower than then the Dev.

The interesting thing to note, is that the js file is minified, and it is showing up as 610KB, when the actual size is 1.99MB.  MS CRM must be doing some additional compressing in order to further decrease the download size, or Chrome lies...

Answer (score 0):

There are several items to answer here related to the loading of the test environment versus production which impact whether it would be any faster in prod.   Performance is a function on how resources are being used, in particular CPU, Disk, Memory and Network.  Understanding how those resources are in use on your existing environment and whether it is different in prod can help you answer your question.   There is also the issue of production differences.

Examples.
a) Dev/QA is on a Virtual machine where the virtual machine host is shared with 50 other VMs.  All access to resources is arbitrated by the hypervisor (all shared, non exclusive) and all must compete for the resources.  The CPU runs at 95%++ all the time and the machine is always swapping - 1Gigabit network.   In production the machine will run on a VM as well, but with a minimum of 4 VMs per host.  It will have it's own exclusive disk, network (10-Gbit), memory and CPU pool not shared with other hosts.   This impacts the delivery chain from disk to in memory cache for often requested items to servicing on the wire.  The more exclusive access to resources without arbitration improves the whole delivery chain on the file (and all files)

b) In production CDN vs no CDN in Dev/QA.  The file will be served from your local CDN node, or ideally out of cache on the client with proper cache management for return visitors.   This beats out the long network chain of request to the server, pull from disk (if not in request cache) and service

c) Different web server in production versus dev/qa.  You are using Apache for your tests but in prod you will use nginex.   One is a sports car and the other a sports racer.   The racer wins on delivery of the files.

d) Compression and optimization.  In prod all files are minified and compressed.  This reduces the network window to pass the file as well as the interrupt service to pull from disk.    Net result, faster delivery of this file and all files subject to the minification and compression.

e) Different hosts in prod.  In production you plan on placing the static files in Amazon versus hosting them all on one server with virtual sites in dev/qa.   This provides a more exclusive delivery path in prod.  Plus, there is the Amazon CDN.

620KB is also significant.  What happens often these days is a lot of development flotsam accumulates in the code pushed out through iterative development cycles.   Makes sure that your file contains only what is needed and no more.   If some JavaScript is not required by this one page, but will be required on downstream pages, consider breaking the file  for smaller chunks on individual pages.   This may seem counterintuitive, but for those users who never visit "Page 42," for which there are 10 JavaScript functions, they have had to wait and wait and wait (and perhaps abandon if a public site) while code that they never will need is pulled.

Smaller files, containing only what is needed for that page, minified, compressed and cached for at least the duration of the session * 2 + CDN will rule the day for your delivery.

Comment: Although this is a very good answer for the common problem, this question is specific to CRM Online.  It is a Platform as a service and Microsoft designates Orgs as either Prod or Non-Prod.  I can choose to host my code base in CRM, or choose to host it else where, and I'm trying to figure out if I'm going to have the same problem in Prod.

Comment: "Best guess," is that Prod equates to larger resource pool and fewer contention issues due to less of a shared pool.  In such a case you should be faster, but by how much is unknown.